# STDOUT as argument in bash / Makefile and handle space properly

Tags: bash, make, games

This is more of a mental practice with bash syntax. I would invite you to take this as a puzzle so we may solve this together. Or as a challenge in understanding bash.

### The Problem

For instance, I have 3 files in a folder `./etc`:

- `./etc`

  - `foo.txt.example`
  - `bar.txt.example`
  - `hello world.txt.example` *(yes, there is space in this file)*

I have constructed the target to do these target, based on the above files, works:

```
make "etc/foo.txt"
make "etc/bar.txt"
make "etc/hello world.txt"
```

So in theory, I can construct a command like this to run all the targets:

```
make "etc/foo.txt" "etc/bar.txt" "etc/hello world.txt"
```

Here comes my question: **Can you construct a bash script that search all** `./etc/*.txt.example` **filenames and construct the above command?**

#### Requirement

1. The answer need to be in the form of a bash command or preferable Makefile target definition;
2. It need to be run-able in most Linux environment by default. It should not require installation of uncommon packages.

---

### What I have Tried

I have already figure out a way in Makefile to get all filenames above:

```
txt:
    for fn in "etc/*.txt.example"; do \
        echo "etc/$$(basename -s ".example" "$$fn")"; \
    done
```

Which basically means running this in bash:

```
for fn in "etc/*.txt.example"; do \
    echo "etc/$(basename -s ".example" "$fn")"; \
done
```

that gives the following output:

```
etc/foo.txt
etc/bar.txt
etc/hello world.txt
```

If you use this loop's output as input of another command, the command seems to treat all space  as seperator of arguments. So this:

```
make $(for fn in "etc/*.txt.example"; do \
    echo "etc/$(basename -s ".example" "$fn")"; \
done)
```

is practically this:

```
make "etc/foo.txt" "etc/bar.txt" "etc/hello" "world.txt"
```

Is there a way to turn the loop's output into arguement that properly preserves the spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You could use arrays:

```
# Get all example files in an array
examples=(etc/*.example)
# Strip the .example suffix from every element of the array
make "${examples[@]%.example}"
```

Or if you have GNU find, sed and xargs (with nul-delimiter support, that is):

```
find etc -iname '*.example' -print0 | sed -z 's/\.example$//' | xargs -0 make
```

Comment: Didn't know about [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). Cool trick!

Answer (score 2):

Creating a nul-delimited list of file names and passing them to `make` via `xargs`:

```
for name in /etc/*.txt.example; do
    printf '%s\0' "${name%.example}"
done | xargs -0 make
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the example files and next create

```
set etc/*.tbl.example
N="shift $#"
for arg
do
   $N; N=;
   set X ${1+"$@"} "$(expr "$arg" '\(.*\).example')"; shift       
done
# and then...
make ${1+"$@"}
```